# vb 2015 Graphics - apparent glitch

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

In the following snippet:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myRect As New Rectangle()
    myRect.Fill = Brushes.Skyblue
End Sub
```

myRect.Fill has a squiggly red line under it, and IntelliSense reports 'Fill' is not a member of 'Rectangle'.

But the Rectangle page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

clearly shows 'Fill' as a property of 'Rectangle'.

Furthermore, the two code lines:

```
 Dim myRect As New Rectangle()
 myRect.Fill = Brushes.SkyBlue
```

are exact copies from that page's example code.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that the assembly and namespace for that are from WPF not WinForms.  In winforms a rect is just the coords, they dont have a color etc.  that is done via Graphics which does have a [FillRectangle Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yysstebh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks (slapping forehead with heel of hand), I'll plead the forest vs. trees syndrome.

Comment: No worries: +1 for even using MSDN!